# Web browser not pulling up after "pressing any key" to login to heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I'm using Git Bash to login to heroku. I'm at the part where I press any key to open the web browser so I can login. I've logged in via the command prompt and it opened the browser just fine. I've tried the heroku login -i method but when I enter my email address it doesn't do anything (just like pressing any key after prompted to do so). I added System32 to my PATH environment variable and have logged in via the command prompt, both of which seem to be the common solutions I can find.

If it helps, I'm trying to push a Python script I've written. I followed Codemy for creating the virtual environment, procfile, requirements.txt, etc. I've used git to add and commit everything, but I get stuck when asked to login. I've successfully logged in via the command prompt.

Comment: You said " I've logged in via the command prompt"... The login is in the we browser, not in the shell. Could you try with cmd instead git bash?

Comment: I've successfully logged in with cmd. When it tells me to press any key in cmd, it works with opening the web browser and I'm able to login. One of the solutions I saw online mentioned to do that, then close the cmd and try with Git Bash. I did that but I still wasn't able to login via heroku after closing cmd

Answer (score 0):

I tried it right now and it worked as expected. There were the steps:

- Download installer https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli
- Install it
- Open the cmd and enter: `heroku login`
- It printed this
  [image]
- then a new tab in my default browser was opened
  [image]
- I entered my credentials with success. It showed the following message:

[image]

- I closed the browser tab and finally I returned to the cmd:

[image]

After these steps, you could use any other git tool to perform git operations. Heroku login is just to store a kind of long live token in some part of the o.s.